# Determine the types of triangle problem issue?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying the hacker rank type of triangle below where based on the 3 sides it has to be determined if the triangle is equilateral, isosceles, scalene, or not a triangle.

Link:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/what-type-of-triangle/problem

Here's my sql code, I don't know what I'm missing but this is failing the test case.

Can anyone help me out with understanding what I'm doing wrong.

```
SELECT CASE
            when t.A = t.B and t.B = t.C then 'Equilateral'
            when t.A = t.B or t.B = t.C or t.C = t.A then 'Isosceles'
            when t.A + t.B <= t.C or t.B + t.C <= t.A or t.C + t.A <= t.B then 'Not A Triangle'
            else 'Scalene' 
       END
FROM TRIANGLES AS t;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this
In a row: 8, the values are 20 20 40, which is actually "NOT A TRIANGLE"
but your solution as it checks for "Isosceles" first, returns "Isosceles"

```
SELECT 
      case 
      when t.A + t.B <= t.C or t.B + t.C <= t.A or t.C + t.A <= t.B then 'Not A Triangle'
      when t.A = t.B and t.B = t.C then 'Equilateral'
      when (t.A = t.B ) or (t.C = t.B ) or (t.A = t.c ) then 'Isosceles'
     else 'Scalene' 
       END
       
from TRIANGLES as t   ;
```

This will help you as we are checking the 'Not A Triangle' case before the 'Isosceles' case